# Makefile:2: *** missing separator. Stop. How can i fix this I am new to Raylib for C++

Tags: raylib

This is my code in `Makefile`

```
default:
g++ ../main.cpp -o test.exe -O2 -Wall -Wno-missing-braces -I ../include/ -L ../lib/ 
- 
lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm.
```

This is my source tree

```
C:.
│   main.cpp
│
└───build
|      Makefile
│
├───include
│       raylib.h
│
└───lib
        libraylib.a
```

I did `cd build` and `mingw32-make` but i get

> Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've wrote your Makefile with spaces instead of tabs. Tabs are mandatory for makefile.
Take a look at this tutorial: https://makefiletutorial.com/